# Endorsed directory isn't working in Tomcat6

Tags: java, tomcat6

Even though it seems that my endorsed directory is configured properly, I keep getting the following message.

```
OpenSAML requires an xml parser that supports JAXP 1.3 and DOM3.
The JVM is currently configured to use the Sun XML parser, which is known
to be buggy and can not be used with OpenSAML.  Please endorse a functional
JAXP library(ies) such as Xerces and Xalan.  For instructions on how to endorse
a new parser see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/standards/index.html
```

In my `tomcat6.conf` I have the following:

```
CATALINA_OPTS = "... -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/etc/tomcat6/endorsed ..."
```

In the `endorsed` folder, I have the following files:

```
resolver-2.9.1.jar    xalan-2.7.1.jar       xml-apis-2.9.1.jar
serializer-2.9.1.jar  xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
```

I've restarted Tomcat6, redeployed my war file and I keep getting the aforementioned error message.

**Update 1**

I ran the following command `jps -v` which gave me this:

3786 Jps -Dapplication.home=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45 -Xms8m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your web application print all the endorsed dirs out to console

```
System.out.println("-Djava.endorsed.dirs = " + 
                     System.getProperty("java.endorsed.dirs"));
```

Check that your directory is listed correctly and there are no other locations adding any conflicting jars.

Comment: Is this the only way? I'll see what I can dig up... huge app, author's days might be numbered (contract bidding ATM)...could I potentially inject a bean that only does this (via the config files) in the Spring app and be done with it?